# Can I use onclick of a button on one page to change image source on a different page. Js

Tags: javascript

I've set up a page for users to change a top level display page with onclick of button. This will change a green circle to a red circle if needs be. The button is on a differnt page to the master page, is this possible to do? I have everything in the same folder with both pages linking to the same .js file. I thought the following function would do the trick but no joy. Thanks.

Control page1:

```
<input type="button" value="Hard Down!" id="Button" onclick="change();">
```

Display page2:

```
<img id="greenCircle" alt= "Circle" src="green.PNG">
```

Function:

```
function change() {
var image = document.getElementById("greenCircle");
image.src = "red.png"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` for communication between tabs (having **same domain**). Setting it on one tab will propagate to all the other tabs. Check the following snippet.

Page A

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
  localStorage.setItem('img_src','red.png')
});
```

Page B

```
addEvent(window, 'storage', function (event) {
  if (event.key == 'img_src') {
    // do your dom manipulation using event.newValue
  }
});
```